# XSLT 1.0 for eliminating duplicates for a specific child node type & to exclude other's

Tags: xslt

I have a XSLT problem to solve, am fairly new to XSLT, the XSLT experts here are awesome, but i could'nt find an exact solution for my problem,I need to eliminate duplicate books & a duplicate in my case is an exact booktype+bookname. but I dont want to apply the duplication to any other nodes like CD or any other nodes within  parent node, the nodes will keep varying,in some exaamples we dont even have a single  node. How will i restrict duplication to be applied to just book node.I have been trying to learn this from an input output perpective here, i may be missing how the actual transformation happens, any help would be a great help

Thanks already!

XML:

```
<ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
  <RowIDWithListOfBooks>
    <ListOfBookInfo>
      <book>
        <BookType>Brand</BookType>
        <BookName>jon</BookName>
      </book>
      <book>
        <BookType>Brand</BookType>
        <BookName>jon</BookName>
      </book>
      <CD>
        <CDType>Country</CDType>
        <CDName>MaxStar</CDName>
      </CD>
    </ListOfBookInfo>
  </RowIDWithListOfBooks>
</ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks>

XSLT:  I have developed so far, Dimitre, thanks much sir! u have been a great help

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!--Key-->
  <xsl:key name="k-books" match="book" use="concat(BookType,'|',BookName)"/>
  <!--Global match template-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--Eliminate duplicate book nodes template-->
  <xsl:template match="ListOfBookInfo">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="book
                [generate-id()
                =generate-id(key('k-books',concat(BookType,'|',BookName))[1])]"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
<RowIDWithListOfBooks>
<ListOfBookInfo><book>
<BookType>Brand</BookType>
<BookName>jon</BookName>
</book></ListOfBookInfo>
</RowIDWithListOfBooks>
</ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/">
<RowIDWithListOfBooks>
<ListOfBookInfo>
<book>
<BookType>Brand</BookType>
<BookName>jon</BookName>
</book>
<CD>
<CDType>Country</CDType>
<CDName>MaxStar</CDName>
</CD>
</ListOfBookInfo>
</RowIDWithListOfBooks>
</ListOfRowIDWithListOfBooks>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't forget to apply templates on other elements that may occur in ListOfBookInfo.

```
<xsl:template match="ListOfBookInfo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book
            [generate-id()
            =generate-id(key('k-books',concat(BookType,'|',BookName))[1])]"/>
        <!-- Apply templates for other element than book -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[name() != 'book']" />

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```